# How to transpose duplicated data in rows into columns

Tags: excel, vba, transpose

I currently trying to clean up a large dataset using Excel VBA. The dataset structure looks like this.

[image]

However, I would like to make it look like this instead, whereby if the cells in columns A:D all contain the same value, transpose the cells in column E. (And remove the duplicated cells from A:D)

[image]

Here is the code I did

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("test")
lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim j As Integer
j = 6

For i = 2 To lastrow

    If (Range("A" & i).Value = Range("A" & i + 1).Value) And (Range("B" & i).Value = Range("B" & i + 1).Value) And (Range("C" & i).Value = Range("C" & i + 1).Value) Then
        Cells(i, j).Value = Cells(i + 1, 5).Value
        j = j + 1
    End If
    
    'Reset J back to 6 if columns A to D does not match previous
    If (Range("A" & i).Value <> Range("A" & i + 1).Value) Or (Range("B" & i).Value <> Range("B" & i + 1).Value) Or (Range("C" & i).Value <> Range("C" & i + 1).Value) Then
        j = 6
    End If
    
Next i
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Is the data always sorted like all `ABCD` come in one block and then `DEFG` starts or an they be mixed?

Comment: It is always sorted in one block.

Comment: However, it can also be `ABCD` followed by `XYCD` (whereby only cells in columns A:B have different values) but I only want to transpose when cells in all 4 columns (from A:D) contain the same values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ended up more complex than I'd thought but seems to work OK

```vb
Sub Compact()

    Const KEY_COLS As Long = 4
    Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Long, k As String, nextEmpty As Long
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    Set ws = Sheets("test")
    For i = 1 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'create a row "key" from first KEY_COLS cells
        k = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose( _
                  ws.Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, KEY_COLS))), "~~")
        
        If Not dict.exists(k) Then
            'move this row up?
            If nextEmpty > 0 Then
                ws.Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, KEY_COLS + 1).Cut ws.Cells(nextEmpty, 1)
                dict.Add k, nextEmpty 'new key - store row#
                nextEmpty = 0
            Else
                dict.Add k, i 'new key - store row#
            End If
        Else
            'seen this key before - move value to that row and clear
            ws.Cells(dict(k), Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Value = _
                ws.Cells(i, KEY_COLS + 1).Value
            ws.Rows(i).ClearContents
            If nextEmpty = 0 Then nextEmpty = i 'available row
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Edit: this is a bit cleaner I think.  It's split into separate "read" and "write" parts.

```vb
Sub Compact2()

    Const KEY_COLS As Long = 4
    Const SEP As String = "~~"
    Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Long, k, col As Long, v
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    Set ws = Sheets("test")
    'collect all the unique combinations and associated values 
    For i = 1 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'create a row "key" from first KEY_COLS cells
        k = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose( _
                  ws.Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, KEY_COLS))), SEP)
        
        If Not dict.exists(k) Then dict.Add k, New Collection
        dict(k).Add ws.Cells(i, KEY_COLS + 1).Value
        ws.Rows(i).ClearContents 'clear row
    Next i
    
    're-populate the sheet from the dictionary
    i = 1
    For Each k In dict
        ws.Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, KEY_COLS).Value = Split(k, SEP)
        col = KEY_COLS + 1
        For Each v In dict(k)
            ws.Cells(i, col) = v
            col = col + 1
        Next v
        i = i + 1
    Next k
End Sub
```

Comment: Cool answer as always (I think I upvote more competing answer from you than anyone else). If you have time, can you take a look at my answer, and see if you can get my solution down to a dynamic formula in column m? Irks me I can't figure it out. I may post a question on it.

Comment: @pgSystemTester - I can take a look later but that formula stuff is mostly beyond me...  I only just got the version with that capability so I'm a bit behind.

Comment: No worries. I'll post it as a question and someone could point out what I'm doing wrong. BigBen or Peh have a history of answering my questions in like 55 seconds and making me feel like I should have known better.

Comment: Posted question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68761456/converting-multidimensional-arrays-into-a-spill-range

Answer (score 1):

### Over Two Years Later...

This will work leveraging the newer function and will by dynamic, no vba required.

```
=LET(alldata,FILTER(A:E,A:A<>""),    zSplitter,"?", zColumnCount,4,
allNames,HSTACK(CHOOSECOLS(alldata,SEQUENCE(1,zColumnCount))),
zNames,UNIQUE(allNames),
keysFiltered, BYROW(zNames,LAMBDA(eRow,TEXTJOIN(zSplitter,TRUE,eRow))),
keysFull,BYROW(allNames,LAMBDA(eRow,TEXTJOIN(zSplitter,TRUE,eRow))),
splitNums,BYROW(keysFiltered,LAMBDA(eRow,TEXTJOIN(zSplitter,TRUE,FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(alldata,zColumnCount+1),keysFull=eRow)))),
zElementCount,BYROW(splitNums,LAMBDA(eRow, LEN(eRow)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(eRow,zSplitter,""))+1)), zMaxCol,MAX(zElementCount),
zSideArray,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(zNames),zMaxCol,LAMBDA(r,c,LET(tempRng,INDEX(splitNums,r,1),tempSplitRng,TEXTSPLIT(tempRng,zSplitter),IF(c>CHOOSEROWS(zElementCount,r),"",CHOOSECOLS(tempSplitRng,c))))),
HSTACK(zNames,zSideArray))
```

### Original Answer

Agree with the Tim Williams this is tricky. I got sort of close to a solution without using VBA in this worksheet (requires spill range enabled). I didn't get a dynamic formula to spill down for the numeric values, but you could make a macro to drag it or something.

[See this spreadsheet.](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiO7_3PtXmZ9g6tQrcB44Kvabaj4ng?e=jPsCG4)

You would need the below formula in cell `i1`

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A:D,NOT(ISBLANK((A:A)))))
```

The following formula would be in `M1`, and dragged down to match the respective columns to the immediate left. You could setup a macro that actually did this for you on a change event. There's probably a way to make this dynamic with an array formula, but I couldn't assemble it in time I tinkered with it.

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(E:E,(NOT(ISBLANK(E:E))*(A:A&B:B&C:C&D:D=I1&J1&K1&L1))))
```

Again if you don't have excel spill range capabilities, this won't work. To view with spill range, checkout the excel file via a web browser so it looks like the below image. The gray cells contain the respective formulas.

[image: Sample of browser result]

Comment: I posted a question regarding my own answer on this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68761456/converting-multidimensional-arrays-into-a-spill-range

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty easily using Power Query

- Group by the first four columns
- Aggregate the 5th column into a delimiter (semicolon) separated text string.
- Split the delimited string into new columns

For the example, I added some rows where the four columns didn't match

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table17"]}[Content],

//set type for all columns as Text
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each {_, Text.Type})),

//group by first four columns, then aggregate the 5th column semicolon separated
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4"}, {
        {"ColE", each Text.Combine([Column5],";"), Text.Type}
    }),

//split the aggregated text into new columns
//may need to edit this step depending on maximum number in the group
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "ColE", 
        Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"ColE.1", "ColE.2", "ColE.3"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{
        {"ColE.1", Int64.Type}, {"ColE.2", Int64.Type}, {"ColE.3", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

[image]